# Unable to run query in MongoDB with case insensitive search

Tags: mongodb

I have a query -

```
db.getCollection('Plan').find(
    {$or:[
        {"_id":{$in:["PLN000000020","PLN000000014"]}},
        {$text:{$search:"test"}}]
    })
  .sort(
      { "name": 1 }
  )
  .skip(0)
  .limit(10)
  .collation(
    {locale:'en'}
 )
```

There is an index on '_id' and a Full text search index ("$**":"text")

This query fails saying - error processing query: ns=Apeiron.Plan limit=10Tree: $or\n _id $in [ \"PLN000000014\" \"PLN000000020\" ]\n TEXT : query=test, language=english, caseSensitive=0, diacriticSensitive=0, tag=NULL\nSort:

{ name: 1.0 }
\nProj: {}\nCollation:

{ locale: \"en\" }
\n planner returned error: Failed to produce a solution for TEXT under OR - other non-TEXT clauses under OR have to be indexed as well.

Whats the workaround? How do I convert this same query into an aggregation query ? I believe that can help me solve the issue?

Comment: The error message is pretty specific here. It's just not allowed. Frankly I'm in agreeance with the core developers on this as "ranked text search results" combined in an OR condition with "regular query results" just makes no sense. When searching "text" you want "nearest matching terms" and regular query conditions are the opposite of that. I suspect your actual use case is that you want to "text search" or if the user chose a different option then use the regular query parameters. And ***that*** would be something entirely different to your current approach.

Comment: But... but..... I'll have to change my entire schema and rewrite code

Comment: To repeat something I said earlier today, If you run up against something with an API which does not work how you want it to, then "you're doing it wrong". As stated, what you are asking for makes no logical sense so "rewriting code" and schema in this instance is a "very good thing". Put the pegs in the holes that are the same shape.